# Check whether UIView is loaded from a Nib/Storyboard or was created programmatically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder, initwithcoder

Is there any way to identify whether a `UIView` is loaded from a nib file/Storyboard, or instantiated dynamically from user code? I am creating a custom `UIView` subclass so I have full access to instance methods.

Would checking whether `initWithCoder:` is called a good idea, or are there other ways too?

*For anyone who wonders why I need such functionality: I am developing a library where I want to smart-resize some views according to their content **only** if they are programmatically created (user won't bother with initialization code, adding layout constraints etc and I will have a simple class method initializer). If user has designed it in Interface Builder, they obviously want to see it as they designed it (I am using IBDesignable/IBInspectable attributes too so IB will heavily be used), so I won't be touching their design.*

Comment: Avoding the questionability of what you are doing, while initWithCoder: can be used without Storyboard, it is unlikely that it will be, so I don't see the problem in implementing a subclass of UIView that has an additional readonly @property initializedWithCoder that determines if the View should be adjusted.